# How to update STL map key1 with key2 and also copy value into key2

Tags: c++, stl

I have an STL map.
I want to change one of the key in the map.
How can can I replace key1 with key2 and then copy value to key2?
map[key2] = value.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to happen if `key1` does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change keys in a map, all you can do it delete the old key and add the new key with the old value.

E.g.

```
auto value = m[key1];
m.erase(key1);
m[key2] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you cannot change a key in a map, the operation you describe doesn't even seem to need this operation... If you say that you want to rename `key1` to `key2`, and then put some new `value` into `key2`, you can just delete `key1` altogether from the map and store `value` into the slot `key2`.

```
m.erase(key1);
m[key2] = value;
```

Comment: How is your answer different from that of @john?

Comment: Do I need to initialise the map iterator after erase ?If I want to insert one more  element to the map how can I do it without corrupting the map ?

Comment: @KunalPuri John's (which I actually upvoted) inserts the value from `key1`, while I understood the question as inserting a new unrelated value; we are interpreting OP's question in a slightly different way. Still, probably it's best to just ask this as a clarification under OP's question.

Comment: @user3509719 what iterator are we talking about? Are you iterating over the map?

Comment: Yes.I am doing a find for key value that returns an iterator to the STL map entry.Then if I do erase and insert.Can you please suggest in this case.

Comment: That's way too scarce information to understand the problem. Of course if you erase an element, all iterators to it (and no one else) become invalidated, how this affects your code depends from how your code works...

Answer (score 0):

You can't just change a key in a `std::map` because they are ordered by key and changing a key would likely put the map out of order. For that reason keys are `const`.

So you have to add a new key and remove the old one. I might do something a bit like this:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
void replace_key(std::map<Key, Value>& map, Key const& key1, Key const& key2)
{
    auto found = map.find(key1);

    if(found == std::end(map))
        throw std::runtime_error("No such key")

    map.emplace(key2, std::move(found->second));
    map.erase(found);
}
```

By *moving* the value to the new key location this should be fairly efficient.